# Object Iteration with DateTime as variable PHP

Tags: php, datetime, object, iteration

I have created a ClientUser Class in PHP that contains a DateTime Object as variable. The class declaration looks something like this (I have excluded some of the other attributes as they are not relevant to the question):

```
class ClientUser {

  public $id = null;
  public $username = null;
  public $dob = null;
  public $telephone = null;

  public function __construct($id){

    if ($id) {
      if (is_numeric($id)) {
          $this->load($id);
      } else {
          $this->getUser($id);
      }
    }

  }

  private function load($id) {
  // SQL Select, statement prepare and result binding;

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
      $this->id = $rid;
      $this->username = $rusername;
      $this->dob = ($rdob != null ? DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_SQL, $rdob) : null);
      $this->telephone = $rtelephone;
    }
  }

}
```

As noticed in the example above, the dob variable is null and gets assigned a value once the SQl statement goes through and pulls the value from the DB. A DateTime object is created from the value in the database and is assigned to the dob variable of the ClientUser object.

The getUser function you see in the construct is used to get the User in case the ID is not provided, so the SQL statement uses the username to get the result.

Now, when the user logs in, I create the ClientUser object and retrieve it from the DB based on the ID. Because there are more than 3 variables the ClientUser object has, I have created a foreach loop to go through all these values so that I can add attributes easily. The iteration looks like this:

```
  $user = new ClientUser($userId);

  foreach($user as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
  }
```

The issue I am encountering is, whenever the loop gets to the 'dob' variable, it stops. All the variables that come after dob, don't get printed. So in this case, for example, telephone does not get printed. The moment I exclude dob from the iteration, all the other variables get printed.

There are no errors on the server, no errors/notice getting printed on HTML. I hope this question is a bit more clear of what I am trying to achieve.

I have added at the bottom an example that should be reproducible.

```
<?php 

class Client {

    public $username = "Condescending";
    public $id = 1234;
    public $dob = null;
    public $telephone = "0722234234";

    public function __construct(){
        $this->dob = DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_SQL, "1971-01-01 00:00:00");
    }

    public function printVariables(){
        foreach($this as $key => $value){
            echo "<br>";
            print "$key => $value\n";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

```
$user = new Client();

print_r($user);

$user->printVariables();
```

Comment: What's the relationship between both snippets? What does `$object` contain?

Comment: That "breakage" will have left a useful error message, right…?

Comment: We don't see where `$object` is declared.  No Repro.

Comment: You're trying to iterate over a DateTime object? But this object has no public properties.

Comment: What. Does. "Break." Mean. Exactly?!

Comment: I have included the relationship between both snippets in the edit of the question.

There is no error message, I would have obviously included it in the question.

Comment: Then what exactly does "break" mean? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: I have checked the error logs on the server, there is nothing that comes up, hence the reason why I don't understand why this happens

Comment: I am not trying to iterate over a DateTime object. I have a class called User that has a dob variable that is a DateTime. I am trying to iterate over the User variables in order to go through each property and get the value. When it gets to the dob variable, the iteration stops.

Comment: Then you'll need to at least present us a *minimal, __reproducible__ example*. Right now we have absolutely nothing to go on.

Comment: I will ask another question and make it a bit more clear.

Comment: That's still not *reproducible*. We don't have the database and whatnot needed to run this. If it's that *object iteration "breaks" when a property is a `DateTime` instance*, that should be easily reproducible with a simple self-contained code snippet. If you cannot produce such a self-contained code snippet that reproduces the issue, then that's a sign that the issue may in fact by somewhere else.

Comment: I have added a reproducible example

Comment: When fixing the missing constant, that *does* give a clear error message… https://3v4l.org/4dgZr

Comment: Apparently the server i was working on had error_reporting set to 0, which is the reason why the errors were not showing. Thank you for your help and for your condescending attitude

Comment: No condescension here, just trying to get to the point.